# Running a python script from php in cmd windows

Tags: python, php

So this is code snippet which isn't working

```
$result = array();
  $cdir = scandir($upload_dir);
  foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
   {
      if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
      {
         if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
         {
          $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
         }
         else
         {
          $result[] = $value;
         }
      }
   }
   print_r($result);
   $f1 = $result[0];
   $f2 = $result[1];
   echo $f1;
   echo $f2;
   $output = exec("python main.py $f1 $f2");
   echo $output;
```

I've also tried using shell_exec but it didn't work. The locations of f1 and f2 are being displayed properly but the python script isn't running and the output is not being shown.

Comment: Is this running in IIS?  If so, it's likely that your Python interpreter isn't in its path.  Just embed the whole path to `python.exe`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I embedded the whole path to python but it didn't work.

Comment: Is your Python file in the same folder as the PHP?  Have you read the documentation?  `exec` only returns the last line of the output.  If you need ALL the output, you either need to pass an output array, or if you're just going to display it, use the `passthru` function.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes , they're in the same folder. I'll try the passthru function.